# Database timestamps returning intriguing values

Tags: javascript, sql, json, sql-server

I am using javascript to read the values of a JSON object that is returned after a GET call.

The database that provides the values is making a timestamp like this:

- 26-04-2019 17:22:25;

  into:
- 1556233200000....

How can I fix this? I have no access to the database.

Comment: That's a Unix epoch time. https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 4):

This is no intriguing value. It is in [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time.

You can simply convert it back to an ISO string by using declaring [JavaScript's Date instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
const dateValue = new Date(1556233200000);
console.log(dateValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

That number (1556233200000) is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 (1/1/1970).

More information about JavaScript date is available here: [Date - JavaScript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).